# Avoid mutating a prop directly error in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, vuetify.js

I created a custom `DateField` component. Everything is working fine but it gives the error `Avoid mutating the prop 'value'`. It occurs when I close the menu by clicking `Cancel` button or clicking outside.

Here is my code -

```
<template>
  <v-menu
    :close-on-content-click="false"
    :return-value.sync="value"
    max-width="290px"
    min-width="290px"
    offset-y
    ref="menu"
    transition="scale-transition"
    v-model="menu"
  >
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-text-field
        :label="label"
        :placeholder="placeholder"
        :value="value"
        @input="$emit('input', $event)"
        v-on="on"
        :hint="hint"
      />
    </template>
    <v-date-picker
      :value="dateValue"
      @change="$emit('input', $event)"
      no-title
      scrollable
      :type="type"
    >
      <v-spacer/>
      <v-btn @click="menu = false" color="primary" text>Cancel</v-btn>
      <v-btn @click="$refs.menu.save(value)" color="primary" text>OK</v-btn>
    </v-date-picker>
  </v-menu>
</template>
```

Comment: Please show the script code

Comment: you're doing `@click="menu = false"`, which I'm guessing menu is referencing the `$store` property. You need to throw a proper commit e.g. `@click=
store.commit('menuOff')"`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give the script part so i'm going to do some assumptions..

In any case, you can use **$emit** that will send a signal to the "father component(the component that passed the menu prop)" and you can receive that signal in the father component using @emitName and changing the value there

Example:

```
<v-btn @click="$emit('cancel')" color="primary" text>Cancel</v-btn>
```

In the father component:

```
<SonComponent :menu="menuData" @cancel="menu=false" />
```

You can learn more from this [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)

Hope this helps.